# css styles does not working only in chrome

Tags: html, css

With the following code I have a problem in Google Chrome where the red text is displayed too low.

I need to place the red sentence above the arrow. It works fine in all browsers except Google Chrome. How can I fix this for Google Chrome?

[image]

---

HTML:

```
<p class = "minimum">Spend an extra {{ shippinglimit | minus: cart.total_price | money }} for free shipping </p>
```

CSS:

```
.minimum {
 color: #FF0000;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 279px;
}
```

Comment: please post a minimal code example (jsbin, jsfiddle, codepen...) that shows the issue, instead of an image.

Comment: Make its parent (the grey box) relative

Comment: That depends on the html surrounding it. Could you post a more elaborate code sample?

Comment: I can't see that sentence neither on firefox. In which other browser it works?

Comment: Then you actually gave us a link without the sentence (I've not found it in the source code).

Comment: You can likely fix this by setting `position: relative` on the `.container`. That should make your absolute positioning less fragile, currently it refers to the `body`. It would be better if you moved the `<p class="minimum">` closer to where you want it to be positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure that position absolute works accordingly with it's parent relative:

For eg:

```
#parentDiv{
  position: relative;
}
#childdiv{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;/*now it's accordingly with #parentDiv*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this does the job:

```
.minimum {
color: #FF0000;
bottom: 306px;
position: relative;
}
```